Consider the PDE \[ 2\frac{y}{x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + (x^2 - y^2) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0 \]
The question goes on to say that Show that along characteristics,
$$
y^2 = x^2 - 2 + C e^{-x^2/2},
$$
where $C \in \mathbb{R}$.
I know I have to use the method of characteristic to solve the PDE but I am struggling to see the trick I can use to simplify the question.

Have you tried to solve the PDE using the method of characteristics? according to the exercise, the characteristics should look like $t\mapsto \gamma_C(t)=\left(t,\pm \sqrt{t^2-2+C\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}}\right)$.

From $$\frac{xdx}{2y}=\frac{dy}{x^2-y^2}$$ follows $$\frac{d(y^2)}{d(x^2)}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2},$$
if we recognize that $2xdx=d(x^2)$ and $d(y^2)=2ydy.$
Now, if we substitute $y^2=y_1$ and $x^2=x_1,$ we obtain $\frac{dy_1}{dx_1}=\frac{x_1-y_1}{2}$ or linear differential equation: $y_1'+\frac{y_1}{2}=\frac{x_1}{2},$ which can be easily solved (with integration factor $e^\frac{x_1}{2}$ for example):
From $$(y_1*e^\frac{x_1}{2})'=x_1*e^\frac{x_1}{2}$$ we get $$y_1*e^\frac{x_1}{2}=\int x_1*e^\frac{x_1}{2} dx_1=(x_1-2)e^\frac{x_1}{2}+C$$
and finally $$y^2=x^2-2+Ce^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$
